# ASCII Space Character in Ruby Unicode Escape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode, encoding, ascii

Doing some reading and came across this block of code on the topic of Unicode Escapes in Ruby:

`money = "\u{20AC 20 A3 20 A5}" # => "€ £ ¥"`

I understand that in this ruby syntax, the actual spaces between the `{}`'s doesn't output an encoded space, that's the reason for the code point `20` but what I don't understand is why there's a code point `20` at the very beginning of the `{}`, right after the `\u`. No space has been output in the result and I copied it verbatim from the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not a `20` at the beginning, it’s `20AC`, which is the code point for `€`. The contents of the braces are a space separated list of codepoints (in hex format). [`20AC` is `€`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm), [`20` is a space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20/index.htm), [`A3` is `£`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a3/index.htm) and [`A5` is `¥`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a5/index.htm).